# induction proof manipulation problem

Tags: proof-writing

starting with the LHS, how do you show

$(k/30)(k+1)(6k^3+9k^2+k-1)+(k+1)^4$= $(k+1)/30(k+2)(6(k+1)^3+9(k+1)^2+(k+1)-1$

as you can probably tell its part of my induction proof but i cant show this how is it done? thanks

Sorry edit its -1 on the end

Comment: the main thing would be NOT to factor the quintic  $ 6k^5 + 15k^4 + 10k^3 - k$   Since leaving off the denominator , add to that $30 (k+1)^4$

Comment: yep, that works